# laptop battery level never reaches 100%

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, battery

When on mains power, the laptop battery shows not charging and the capacity fails to reach 100%.

I saw a similar issue on another laptop i had. entering device manager and deleting the battery driver and restart, fixed the issue for that laptop. However for the 3 other laptops i have, this didn't fix the issue.

all 4 laptops are HP 6550b Windows 7 Pro HP OEM

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quite often laptop manufacturers will set a limit to charge/discharge percentage to protect the battery (ie. to prolong battery life).

e.g. charge at 85%, stop at 95%

these kind of things
look into the power manager application/ power options in control panel to see if there are settings to change. Otherwise you may want to recalibrate thhe battery (i.e. run down the battery completely then recharge it again to top)

Answer (score 0):

If they are older batteries, this would be entirely normal as batteries lose capacity over time and are unable to recharge to the level they used to be able to.  If they are newer, then bubu provided a couple of excellent reasons/suggestions.