# Has my laptop battery lost 40% of its capacity?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, battery-life, dell-precision

The past few (work) days, I have noticed that at the end of the day, Windows was reporting that my laptop was plugged in, my battery was not fully charged, and that the system was not charging the battery. On one day, Windows reported that the battery was at 60%, and on another day, Windows reported that the battery was at 61%. My case appears to have been identical to [laptop battery level never reaches 100%](https://superuser.com/questions/223003/laptop-battery-level-never-reaches-100). I performed a recalibration, as described in the accepted answer. After doing so, I allowed the battery to charge. Windows is now reporting that the battery is at 100% and fully charged.

Does this mean that at full charge, my battery is now only 60% of its original capacity?

Comment: in elevated cmd prompt run "powercfg -energy "  In there is design capacity and last full charge in mWh.  This should give you some insight.

Comment: Be sure to look for firmware updates too just in case. Batteries do not last forever so the usual lifespan of a laptop battery is about three years and that's typically why laptop batteries do not come with any warranty after such a period. In any case, just mentioning this in case it's an old battery or you have another to plug in to test, etc. you can think about it some and weigh in on some options.

Comment: Thanks. If I'm doing my math right, the designed capacity for my battery is 99,900 units, and the last full charge was only 53,746 units, so my battery is at roughly 54% of its original capacity? I guess maybe the 60% stopping point was coincidental. Looking at old emails and the install log, it appears that this laptop just had its fourth birthday last month, so I guess I've done all right with this one.